# Linking error floating point formats not linked

Tags: c, floating-point, emulation

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    struct book
    {
        char name;
        float price;
        int pages;
    };

    struct book b[100];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i <= 99; i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter name price and pages");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%c%f%d", &b[i].name, &b[i].price, &b[i].pages);
    }

    for (i = 0; i<99; i++)
        printf("\n%c %f %d", b[i].name, b[i].price, b[i].pages);
}
```

And the biggest dilemma , how it can be solved by just adding a function , not even calling that function
    i.e

```
linkfloat()
{
    float a = 0, *b;
    b = &a;
    a = *b;
}
```

How this ambiguity can be removed by just adding the function declaration and definition and not even calling it inside the main function?

Comment: Irrelevent to problem but `fflush(stdin);` ?? Don't do that.

Comment: I think it's necessary to flush the data present in input buffer @ameyCU

Comment: Are you targeting an embedded system that doesn't have floating point hardware?

Comment: As for the `fflush` issue, the C and C++ specifications mentions it to explicitly be *undefined behavior* if done on `stdin`. Some systems implement it as an extension, but if you want your code to be portable (especially to smaller systems) then don't do it. Read until you get a newline instead.

Comment: I am just experimenting with structures and ended up this , by some google sources said that some processors lack float computations and hence they use emulator , but this is not convencing

Comment: Anything to do with linkers or floating point emulators will be system dependent, not an inherent feature of the C language.  Hence you will need to describe your environment (OS, compiler, architecture, etc) to have a chance of getting a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the processors are not equipped with the computations on float and hence for better performance the computer system uses an Emulator for carrying out the computations related to float 
                             Since in some cases it is possible even when a reference to a float is there but the compiler do not detect the need of an Emulator but when float is encountered a flag has been set in the Emulator to have the linker(which combines the object file to produce the executable file) link , but now since the compiler do not detect the need of Emulator therefore we are getting Error-"Floating Point Formats not linked".
                                                         One such case in which the compiler does not detect the need of the Emulator is while receiving the float value using scanf , therefore we r getting this problem here.
                                                                  By using the link float function , it gives enough computations on float to the compiler that the compiler now demands for the Emulator